# button radio wont stay checked after update Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I m trying to implement query with custom fields on my local wordpress website.

All works like a charm except when I check the radio button, this one want to be checked...

Can you help me please ? thanks for your reply.

```
    <div id="archive-filters">
<?php foreach( $GLOBALS['my_query_filters'] as $key => $name ): 
$field = get_field_object($key);
if( isset($_GET[ $name ]) ) {
$field['value'] = explode(',', $_GET[ $name ]);
}
    // create filter
    ?>
    <div class="filter" data-filter="<?php echo $name; ?>">
        <?php create_field( $field ); ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    // change
    $('#archive-filters').on('change', 'input[type="radio"]', function(){
        var url = '';
            args = {};
        $('#archive-filters .filter').each(function(){
            var filter = $(this).data('filter'),
                vals = [];
            $(this).find('input:checked').each(function(){
vals.push( $(this).val() );

            });

        // append to args
            args[ filter ] = vals.join(',');

        });


        // update url
        url += '?';


        // loop over args
        $.each(args, function( name, value ){

            url += name + '=' + value + '&';
                    });

        // remove last &
        url = url.slice(0, -1);


        // reload page
        window.location.replace( url );

    });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Please clarify.

Comment: @Difster when I checked the button, this one is uncheck after refresh.